# Mapping a table's components as arraylist in another table as onetomany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm using JPA with hibernate persistence manager.

I have two classes, **LibraryLoanSystem.java** and **User.java**.

**LibraryLoanSystem.java**

```
 @Entity
    public class LibraryLoanSystem {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer idOfLLS;

        @Transient
        private ArrayList<Loan> loans = new ArrayList<Loan>();

        @Transient
        private ArrayList<Loanable> loanables = new ArrayList<Loanable>();

        @OneToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "USER" , joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "studentId"))
        private ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

        @Transient
        private ObservableList<Material> materialData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        public LibraryLoanSystem() {

            populateUsers();
            populateMaterials();
        } //getters,setters and methods
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {

    /* Name of the User */
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    /* Date of Birth for the User */
    @Column(name = "dateOfBirth",nullable = false)
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    /* Student ID of the User */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "studentId", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String studentId;
//constructor,getters & setters
```

Basically, **ArrayList users** in libraryloansystem is the list of all users in the system, aka. all of the user records in the user table rows. These two java classes have an aggregation relationship between them, onetomany, with libraryloansystem having multiple users but the user having only one system. I'm unsure on how to map them, and I get

> Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany
>   or @CollectionOfElements: controller.LibraryLoanSystem.users

On my attempts. How can I map this arraylist correctly?Thanks

Comment: (1) Why are you trying to give the same name to the entity table (`@Table(name = "User"...`) and the join table (`@JoinTable(name = "USER"...`)? (2) Don't try to force a specific list implementation. Use `private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of: 
`private ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();`

use: `private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();`

As the documentation states ([link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html)):

> Hibernate requires that persistent collection-valued fields be declared as an interface type. The actual interface might be java.util.Set, java.util.Collection, java.util.List, java.util.Map, java.util.SortedSet, java.util.SortedMap or anything you like ("anything you like" means you will have to write an implementation of org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType.)